# Can I control reflection intensity with a map in three.js?

Tags: typescript, reflection, three.js, graphics, 3d

I'm currently working on a project where I would like to control what portions of the material have reflectivity. I was hoping this could be achievable with something like an alpha/specular/bump map but just for reflectivity.

Right now I can kind of emulate this by drawing two pieces of replicated geometry stacked on top of each. I have a material for the bottom piece that is reflective and then I have a non reflective material on the top piece that has an alpha map with the content I don't want reflected. I'm guessing this could be done with a custom shader, but I don't want to go that route unless I have to. Any help would be much appreciated!